# atomic read from sqlite database while it is being written to

Tags: sqlite, pysqlite

Is it possible to read from a sqlite database while it is being written to?

How would one go about accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this section of the SQLite FAQ's](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) and also [this one](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6).

Basically, since the database isn't controlled by a "proper" DBMS (i.e. a server) there a limitations as to what can be done with it. For instance, you have to wait until one transaction is completed before starting another. Fortunately, the SQLite library does some checking to see if the database is being modified by another library-handled connection before it starts doing stuff to the database.